# Windows Azure Service Management from Python has certificate issue

Tags: python, azure

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
In Windows Azure account .cer file uploaded.

my python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from azure import *
from azure.servicemanagement import *

azureId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
certificate_path= "/home/dharampal/Desktop/azure.pem";

sms = ServiceManagementService(azureId,certificate_path)
print sms
result = sms.list_locations()
print result
```

when scripts runs that time getting ServiceManagementService object but certificate related error thrown.

output of the script is :

```
    <azure.servicemanagement.servicemanagementservice.ServiceManagementService object at 0xb7259f2c>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "available_locations_list.py", line 13, in <module>
    result = sms.list_locations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicemanagement/servicemanagementservice.py", line 796, in list_locations
    Locations)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicemanagement/servicemanagementclient.py", line 96, in _perform_get
    response = self._perform_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicemanagement/servicemanagementclient.py", line 83, in _perform_request
    resp = self._filter(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/http/httpclient.py", line 144, in perform_request
    self.send_request_headers(connection, request.headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/http/httpclient.py", line 125, in send_request_headers
    connection.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 141, in __init__
    ciphers)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336265218] _ssl.c:351: error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
```

where am i doing wrong ? 
if any one faced same issue and got solution, please help me. 
did google but unable to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, so I am not sure why you are seeing a failure, but I can point you at a [complete example in Python](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/azure/technical-papers.aspx) that creates a pem, uploads cer, and shows some Service Management code in Python.

It might rather be how your pem was created. Python Service Management worked for me with a pem and cer created using the following commands (then uploading corresponding cer to Windows Azure Management Cert Store):

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem -subj "/CN=This Name Shows in the Portal"
openssl x509 -inform pem -in mycert.pem -outform der -out mycert.cer
```

Note the "-subj" param is handy to control the text that shows up in the Windows Azure Portal for Certificates so you can tell them apart.

There is also a longer [list of Windows Azure papers](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/azure/technical-papers.aspx), several of which show examples using Python (including the one referenced above).

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact error I get on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS if the `certificate_path` is incorrect (typo in the directory or file name).  So please double check that yours is correct.